# Issue while creating visual attributes

Tags: jquery-ui, magento

Please refer to: http://blog.4aal.nl/post/visualize-your-magento-attributes
I'm creating visual attributes.

I started this process by altering `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`

In configurable.phtml, I replaced:

`<script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    </script>`

with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#attribute158").visualAttribute();
</script>
```

In head tag I'm including:
`http://blog.4aal.nl/var/uploads/06/magento.visual.attribute.js`

After making all these changes in my frontend, default dropdown option gets hidden, but the block sizes in small boxes are not showing. My page source is only showing `<ul class="va_wrapper" id="va_wrapper_1" rel="attribute158"></ul>`

The only problem is that it's not showing li tag....

I thought the problem was with the loop code placed in the jscript file. The loop code looks like:

```
//loop all stored options and create custom html
        var pos = 0;
        if (options.length) {
            for (var index in options) {
                if (!isNaN(index)) {
                    pos++;
                    var value = index;
                    var text = options[index].text;
                    options[index].position = pos;
                    if (!settings.useTitle) {
                        description = '';
                    }
                    wrapper.append('<li title="' + description + '" class="opt_' + value + '"><a href="#' + value + '">' + text + '</a></li>');
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm using a configurable product.
Please tell me whats wrong in my steps.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to replace the code in `configurable.phtml`. You only need to add the following code
at the end of the file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId(); ?>").visualAttribute();
</script>
```